# Only LAST tuple displayed as HTML table is populated with delimited file with PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have this type of record in an HTML table:

```
<tr class="simplehighlight" onclick="window.location.href='./games/game191.php';">
<td>06/09/2007</td><td>Jennifer Woods Memorial Grand Prix</td><td>C54</td>
<td>Nikolayev, Igor</td><td>2431</td><td>Parry, Matt</td><td>2252</td><td class="text-center">1-0</td></tr>
```

I want to read in a delimited file, make an array, and populate the table: (sample record)

```
game191|06/09/2007|Jennifer Woods Memorial Grand Prix|C54|Nikolayev, Igor|2431|Parry, Matt|2252|1-0
```

I tried this, but it only displays the last record from the datafile (`/games.csv`)

```
<?php
// open delimited data file "|" if needed and read.
//game191|06/09/2007|Jennifer Woods Memorial Grand Prix|C54|Nikolayev, Igor|2431|Parry,         Matt|2252|1-0

if(!isset($_SESSION['games_array'])) {$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/games.csv'; 
$fp = fopen($file,"r"); $list = fread($fp, filesize($file)); 
$_SESSION['games_array'] = explode("\n",$list); fclose($fp);}

// extract variables from each tuple by iteration
foreach ($_SESSION['games_array'] as $v);{
$token = explode("|", $v);

//write the table row and table data
echo "<tr class=\"simplehighlight\" onclick=\"window.location.href='./games/"; 
echo $token[0]; echo ".php';\">"; 
echo "<td>";echo $token[1];echo "</td>"; echo "<td>";echo $token[2];echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";echo $token[3];echo "</td>"; echo "<td>";echo $token[4];echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";echo $token[5];echo "</td>"; echo "<td>";echo $token[6];echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";echo $token[7];echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"; echo $token[8];echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";}; 
?>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['games_array'] as $v);{
```

should be

```
foreach ($_SESSION['games_array'] as $v) {
```

Comment: If I had a dime for every time I've made that mistake... well, I'd have a few dimes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try with file():

```
$lines = file('filename');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have the right permissions to access that file? is your php error_reporting set to display all errors? you could try using only relative paths, have you tried that? try using file_get_contents...

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler than I thought... I erred in reusing old junk code from another script.

I found this and it works!

```
<?php
$text = file('games.csv'); foreach($text as $line) {$token = explode("|", $line);
echo "<tr class=\"simplehighlight\" onclick=\"window.location.href='./games/"; 
echo $token[0]; echo ".php';\">"; 
echo "<td>";echo $token[1];echo "</td>"; echo "<td>";echo $token[2];echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";echo $token[3];echo "</td>"; echo "<td>";echo $token[4];echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";echo $token[5];echo "</td>"; echo "<td>";echo $token[6];echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";echo $token[7];echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"; echo $token[8]; echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";}; 
?>
```

Let me know if you see any improvements or faster functions. Thank you !

Comment: It works because your `foreach` uses the correct syntax, whereas your  original example does not (see my answer above).  And another suggestion: use proper indentation - it will help you catch this kind of error.

Comment: I mostly use single quotation. This way you can use doublequotes in your string without escaping it. Making the code more readable. And when using single quoting style the string won't get parsed. However performance wise it's really not a big difference.